# SQL Server - find out active customers in given date range

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a customers table

**TBLCustomer**:

```
CustomerCode    StartDate    EndDate
-----------------------------------------
C1               2016-02-01    2016-05-01
C2               2016-05-01    2016-12-01
C3               NULL          2016-05-01
C4               2016-07-01    NULL
C5               NULL          NULL
```

Now I want to write a query to find out customers which are active on a current date on following conditions.

1. If both start and end date are not blank, then customer is active between given date range.
2. If start date is NULL and end date is there then customer is active till enddate.
3. If start date is there and end date is NULL then customer is active from startdate.
4. If start and end date are NULL , then customer is always active.

Sample output:

Current Date: 2016-04-07

```
CustomerCode    
----------------
C1               
C3               
C5
```

Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: post some sample output based on above table

Comment: why is c2 and c3 excluded ,you have to post some examples on why you are excluding them and what is the reason for including rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of implementing your logic would be to use the `COALESCE()` function on the `StartDate` and `EndDate`.  In cases where the `StartDate` be `NULL`, you can replace it with a very early date (the year 1753 in my example below).  Then, if the `StartDate` be missing, a customer will effectively be treated as if he were always there.  I apply similar logic for the `EndDate`.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TBLCustomer t
WHERE someDate BETWEEN COALESCE(StartDate, CAST('1753-1-1' AS DATETIME)) AND
                       COALESCE(EndDate, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply provide an ISNULL with a date that will be well before/after the bounds:

ie.

```
WHERE @ActiveDate BETWEEN ISNULL(StartDate, '1900-01-01') AND ISNULL(EndDate, '2100-01-01')
```